# Efficient programming to overcome memory limit in R

Tags: r

I have a function that calculates an index in R for a matrix of binary data. The goal of this function is to calculate a person-fit index for binary response data called HT. It divides the covariance between response vectors of two respondents (e.g. person *i* & *j*) by the maximum possible covariance between the two response patterns which can be calculated using the mean of response vectors(e.g. Bi).The function is:

```
fit<-function(Data){
        N<-dim(Data)[1]
        L<-dim(Data)[2]
        r <- rowSums(Data)          
        p.cor.n <- (r/L)    #proportion correct for each response pattern           
        sig.ij <- var(t(Data),t(Data)) #covariance of response patterns
        diag(sig.ij) <-0
        H.num <- apply(sig.ij,1,sum)
        H.denom1 <- matrix(p.cor.n,N,1) %*% matrix(1-p.cor.n,1,N)  #Bi(1-Bj)
        H.denom2 <- matrix(1-p.cor.n,N,1) %*% matrix(p.cor.n,1,N)  #(1-Bi)Bj
        H.denomm <- ifelse(H.denom1>H.denom2,H.denom2,H.denom1)
        diag(H.denomm) <-0
        H.denom <- apply(H.denomm,1,sum)
        HT <- H.num / H.denom
        return(HT)
        }
```

This function works fine with small matrices (e.g. 1000 by 20) but when I increased the number of rows (e.g. to 10000) I came across to memory limitation problem. The source of the problem is this line in the function:

```
H.denomm <- ifelse(H.denom1>H.denom2,H.denom2,H.denom1)
```

which selects the denominator for each response pattern.Is there any other way to re-write this line which demands lower memory?

P.S.: you can try `data<-matrix(rbinom(200000,1,.7),10000,20)`.

Thanks.

Comment: To the spirit of smci below...Some background about the goal would help. What are you expecting the default assumptions R makes when you ask if one matrix is "greater" than another one. I'd dig into that.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to test something like denom1 - denom2 is semi positive definite?

Comment: @miles2know With greater matrix I meant larger sample of respondents.No, there's no testing such for semi-positive definite.It's a simple calculation.

Answer (score 3):

Well here is one way you could shave a little time off. Overall I still think there might be a better theoretical answer in terms of the approach you take....But here goes. I wrote up an Rcpp function that specifically implements ifelse in the sense you use it in above. It only works for square matrices like in your example. BTW I wasn't really trying to optimize R ifelse because I'm pretty sure it already calls internal C functions. I was just curious if a C++ function designed to do exactly what you are trying to do and nothing more would be faster. I shaved 11 seconds off. (This selects the larger value).

**C++ Function:**

```
library(Rcpp)
library(inline)

    code <-"
        Rcpp::NumericMatrix x(xs);
        Rcpp::NumericMatrix y(ys);
        Rcpp::NumericMatrix ans (x.nrow(), y.ncol());
          int ii, jj;

          for (ii=0; ii < x.nrow(); ii++){
            for (jj=0; jj < x.ncol(); jj++){
          if(x(ii,jj) < y(ii,jj)){
           ans(ii,jj) = y(ii,jj);
          } else {
           ans(ii,jj) = x(ii,jj);
          }
         }
        }
        return(ans);"

    matIfelse <- cxxfunction(signature(xs="numeric",ys="numeric"),
                    plugin="Rcpp",
                    body=code)
```

Now if you replace ifelse in your function above with matIfelse you can give it a try. For example:

```
     H.denomm <- matIfelse(H.denom1,H.denom2)

    # Time for old version to run with the matrix you suggested above matrix(rbinom(200000,1,.7),10000,20)
    #  user   system  elapsed 
    #  37.78  3.36    41.30 

    # Time to run with dedicated Rcpp function
    #  user   system  elapsed 
    #  28.25  0.96    30.22
```

Not bad roughly 36% faster, again though I don't claim that this is generally faster than ifelse just in this very specific instance. Cheers

P.s. I forgot to mention that to use Rcpp you need to have [Rtools](http://cran.at.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) installed and during the install make sure environment path variables are added for Rtools and gcc. On my machine those would look like: c:\Rtools\bin;c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin

**Edit:**

I just noticed that you were running into memory problems... So I'm not sure if you are running a 32 or 64 bit machine, but you probably just need to allow R to increase the amount of RAM it can use. I'll assume you are running on 32 bit to be safe. So you should be able to let R take at least 2gigs of RAM. Give this a try:  `memory.limit(size=1900)`  size is in megabytes so I just went for 1.9 gigs just to be safe. I'd imagine this is plenty of memory for what you need.

Comment: Thanks.It's interesting that For loops in C++ are faster that those in R.I'm not familiar with C or C++ so I would be happier to have a solution in R terminology rather than C++.

Comment: Hi Amin. I hear you on wanting a more familiar R-centric solution. The R package Rcpp was developed to help integrate c into the R development process when needed. So loops are not faster in c++ than in R in fact most of base R is written in c. I think the reason my idea was faster was because ifelse has to do a lot more e.g It needs to test what kind of objects it is comparing and then pick a method for that comparison. So I think the speed up came from getting rid of method dispatch.

Comment: end of the day not completely sure why this was faster, but it's interesting to think about. BTW working with really large matrices can take time and if you only have to do this a few times 35-40 seconds isn't such a big deal...

Comment: Thanks for your input.There should be a more efficient way for that calculation. My problem is not timing is the limit of working memory. I just found out that this index has been coded in R in a package called "PerFit" you may want to take look and may be able to help me improve my code. The function in that package is called "Ht". Here's the link to the package: [PerFit](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=1878)

Comment: cool man thanks I'll look into PerFit... go with that. good luck with you're larger questions.

Comment: So far I found `mapply(min,H.denom1,H.denom2)` as an alternative to `ifelse(H.denom1>H.denom2,H.denom2,H.denom1)` but the memory problem still exists! But it needs to assign dimension as N by N.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually intend to do NxL independent `ifelse((H.denom1>H.denom2,...` operations?

```
H.denomm <- ifelse(H.denom1>H.denom2,H.denom2,H.denom1)
```

If you really do, look for a library or alternatively, a better decomposition.
If you told us in general terms what this code is trying to do, it would help us answer it.

Comment: I just added more description. Yes, I need to compare each cell of `H.denom1` with `H.denom2` and select the smaller value. This is part of the calculation procedure. I can use a `for loop` but I'm quite sure it will be slower than `ifelse`.